# How to create a specific html structure for datatables search bar?

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatables

I'm trying to add this structure to the searchbar:

```
<div class="app-search">
  <form>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search...">
      <span class="mdi mdi-magnify"></span>
      <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Search</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Actually I tried to add this code to my `datatables`:

```
$("#example-datatable").DataTable({
    keys: !0,
    "dom": '<"input-group"f><"#toolbar.dt-box">lrtip',
```

but the result is completely wrong as you can see from this [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xu4fdpk9/7/).

The final result should be this:

[image]

What I did wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not able to explain what is wrong in your code, but I can share my solutions for this. I hope it will drive you to the right solution.

By adding this to your table object, you are able to delete "Search:" before the input:

```
let table = $('#example').DataTable( {
 language: { search: "" }
});
```

You can run this function to be able to change the input's placeholder:

```
$('.dataTables_filter input').attr("placeholder", "SEARCH");
```

You can also replace all input element using this function:

```
$('.dataTables_filter label').html('<input type="search" class="" placeholder="I am the new input" aria-controls="example">');
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0da982ue/9/

Comment: could you please provide a fiddle?

Comment: the customization is correct but now the search bar doesn't work, same in your fiddle

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice that. I updated the link with working one. You need to add some styles there.