# How to replace search dom in datatables plugin

Tags: jquery, datatables, datatables-1.10

How does one replace the search input DOM in datatables all.

I have tried a couple of techniques. All I can replace is the filter but I want to keep that, I have already built a custom search.

I want to replace the search area with the export buttons. I know how to add them but I cannot figure how to replace the search field with the buttons.

Here is the image of what I have currently

[image]

Comment: I think my answer from other topic can help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/52296383/9946758

Comment: look at [this](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.search), may help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create a specific html structure for datatables search bar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52254517/how-to-create-a-specific-html-structure-for-datatables-search-bar)

Comment: Hi @Adam Thanks for the response. I think what you are referring to is the placeholder.  I want to remove the search input and place the export buttons in its place

Comment: What about this $('.dataTables_filter label').html($('.dt-buttons ')); ?
It is based on answer from comment above.

Comment: Will check it out. Thank you

Comment: Hi, if you want to disable the default search you can define a new dom without including the search form and move buttons on the right using css. Take a look here for the dom options: https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom